# how to create crontab for auto run command "service php-fpm restart" in centos 6?

Tags: php, linux, cron, centos6

I want to run command "service php-fpm restart" each 1 minute and I tried to using contab.

I tried this code in contab file:

```
0/1 * * * * service php-fpm restart
```

In the file crontab from /var/spool/con/root, I put these code:

```
0 2 * * * chown -R nginx:nginx /home/
0 3 * * * echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
0 4 * * * reboot
0/1 * * * * service php-fpm restart
```

All the command almost are running , but the command "service php-fpm restart" not.

Comment: xy problem why do you need to restart that service each minute?

Comment: because I have a problem with update thumnail/upload image in wordpress, I using nginx for run our wordpress, and I fix this error by restart php-fpm

Comment: so you are rebooting you server each day for some thumbnail/image upload, nice one, better fix the root problem then the symptoms,what problems do you have with your thumbnails?

Comment: I can't update thumbnail and upload image to library in wordpress, don't understand with this error, but when I run command restart php-fpm, the problem solve. so I want to this command run every minute.

Comment: i think you have problems with permissions or with php, i don't recommend restarting your server each day and restarting a service each minute

Comment: i think `php-fpm` is not design to restart each minute

Comment: I don't known... I run 80 site on 1 server 8gb ram, swap 16gb, I think it related this error.

Comment: so this error happens on all your wordpress instalations?

Comment: yes. all of wordpress error.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the big question of why you need to restart every minute (feels like fixing a flat by making sure you have a airpump handy instead of stopping the leak) I wonder how you got a minute of "0/1"? To run something every minute you give it five stars

```
* * * * * /sbin/service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: Thanks but seem it still not work, I use centos 6.64

Comment: I don't see php-fpm file in /sbin/ folder.

Comment: no, php-fpm is in /etc/rc.d/init.d/ but the service command is in /sbin and that will then call /etc/rc.d/init.d/php-fpm